# JMETER load testing using CSV dataset config throwing unsupported media type error

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to do the load test in JMeter using CSV dataset config.

It is throwing an unsupported media type error.

[Created thread group looping 100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkL3X.png)

[CSV file saved in bin folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoOJC.png)

[Cookie Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mILzs.png)

[Header Manager with content and encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRdM9.png)

[HTTP request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6uZj.png)

[Using json extractor extract the refno to pass the value in another request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIvwP.png)

[Passing the refno and apikey and user to another request to get the final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aCMk.png)

[Getting Unsupported Media type error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZpF1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the [Content-Type header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) you're sending with the [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) is not accepted by your application

Try disabling it so JMeter would send the default one: [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/x-www-form-urlencoded) and if it doesn't help - ask around which exactly Content-Type you should be supplying

More information: [415 Unsupported Media Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415)